# Auto-register a base class in Coffeescript/Javascript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Given a set of Coffeescript classes like this:

```
class A

class B extends A

class C extends B
```

Is there a way to get a list of subclasses of A, such that one could register them e.g.

```
A.types = {}
A.types[class.name] = class for class in subclasses(A)
```

to get

```
A = {
  "A": A,
  "B": B,
  "C": C
}
```

The only thing that comes to mind is to manually add each class to the `A.types`, but I was just curious if there was a way to automate this.

I expect there is a question and answer like this out there already, but I was unable to find it.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, may i ask you to accept an answer?

Answer (score 1):

The only way i can think of, is registering all these classes inside some kind of a namespace, and add a method of finding subclass inside this namespace, something like this:

```
App =
    findSub: (obj) ->
        item for className, item of @ when className isnt 'findSub' and ((item.__super__ is undefined and item is obj) or item.__super__ is obj.prototype or item.__super__ instanceof obj)           

class App.A

class App.B extends App.A

class App.C extends App.B

class App.D

console.log App.findSub App.A // [A(), B(), C()]
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9j9ugkbc/)

Comment: Thanks. I like this and I think it is pretty clever.

Comment: You're welcome. Also, your question is a very good example of why i don't consider JavaScript an OOP language - the lengths you have to go to build event a simplest contracting system are amazing, and that's why i prefer to do things in JS functional way more and more. Or use some framework, like `Ember`.

Comment: Yeah, using Coffeescript feels like doubling down on the wrongness. :)

Comment: No, CoffeeScript allows for this piece of beauty: `y = (f) -> ((g) -> (x) -> f(g(g))(x))((g) -> (x) -> f(g(g))(x))`, and also there's one gem of insight of `https://leanpub.com/coffeescript-ristretto/read`